# Django slow inner join on a table with more than 10 million records

Tags: mysql, sql, django, query-optimization

I am using mysql with Django. I am trying to count the number of visitor_pages for a specific dealer in a certain amount of time.
I would share the raw sql query that I have obtained from django debug toolbar.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count`
  FROM `visitor_page`
INNER JOIN `dealer_visitors`
    ON (`visitor_page`.`dealer_visitor_id` = `dealer_visitors`.`id`)
WHERE (`visitor_page`.`date_time` BETWEEN '2021-02-01 05:51:00'
                                      AND '2021-03-21 05:50:00'
  AND `dealer_visitors`.`dealer_id` = 15)
```

The issue is that I have more than 13 million records in the visitor_pages table and about 1.5 million records in the dealer_visitor table. I have already indexed date_time. I am thinking of using a materialized view but before attempting that, I would really appreciate suggestions on how I could improve this query.

visitor_pages schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor_page` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_id` int NOT NULL,
  `dealer_visitor_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `visitor_page_page_id_246babdf_fk_web_page_id` (`page_id`),
  KEY `visitor_page_dealer_visitor_id_e2dddea2_fk_dealer_visitors_id` (`dealer_visitor_id`),
  KEY `visitor_page_date_time_06e9e9f5` (`date_time`),
  CONSTRAINT `visitor_page_dealer_visitor_id_e2dddea2_fk_dealer_visitors_id` FOREIGN KEY (`dealer_visitor_id`) REFERENCES `dealer_visitors` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `visitor_page_page_id_246babdf_fk_web_page_id` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `web_page` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13626649 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

dealer_visitors schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `dealer_visitors` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `visit_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dealer_id` int NOT NULL,
  `visitor_id` int NOT NULL,
  `type` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` longtext,
  `location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dealer_visitors_dealer_id_306e2202_fk_dealer_id` (`dealer_id`),
  KEY `dealer_visitors_visitor_id_27ae498e_fk_visitor_id` (`visitor_id`),
  KEY `dealer_visitors_type_af0f7d79` (`type`),
  KEY `dealer_visitors_visit_date_f2b138c9` (`visit_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `dealer_visitors_dealer_id_306e2202_fk_dealer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`dealer_id`) REFERENCES `dealer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `dealer_visitors_visitor_id_27ae498e_fk_visitor_id` FOREIGN KEY (`visitor_id`) REFERENCES `visitor` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1524478 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE the query gives me the following:
[image: EXPLAIN ANALYZE]

EXPLAIN:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the models and any indexes you have?

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question. You haven't given us enough information to help you. It's unlikely your indexing is "good to go" if your query is slow.

Comment: You've indexed `date` or `date_time`?  I ask because you don't use `date` in your query.  Also, for best support, please include the actual table definitions, including indexes, etc, and the actual `EXPLAIN` plan for the query; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-analyze

Comment: @MatBailie I have indexed date_time. Edited the question to add more details

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the distribution of the data, the Optimizer might pick one of the tables to start with, or pick the other.  So, let's provide optimal indexes for each case:

```
   ON `visitor_page`.`dealer_visitor_id` = `dealer_visitors`.`id`
WHERE `visitor_page`.`date_time` BETWEEN ...
  AND `dealer_visitors`.`dealer_id` = 15
```

Starting with `visitor_page`:

```
 visitor_page:  INDEX(date_time)   -- (already exists)
 dealer_visitors:  (already has PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Starting with `dealer_visitors`:

```
 dealer_visitors:  INDEX(dealer_id)   -- (already exists)
 visitor_page:  INDEX(dealer_visitor_id, date_time)  -- in this order
```

and drop `dealer_visitors_visitor_id_27ae498e_fk_visitor_id` as now being redundant.

The net is to add one index and drop one index.

Materialized view -- It is often best for Data Warehouse reports to build and incrementally maintain a "summary table" (a "materialized view").  The very odd date range (1 month + 20 days - 61 seconds) makes this clumsy to do.  Typically it is handy to make the table based on whole days.  If you can shift to daily (or hourly), then see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Something else to check:  How much RAM do you have?  What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';` say?

I see that the tables have different charset/collation.  This is not a problem for the query in question, but if you have other queries that `JOIN` on `VARCHARs`, check that they use the same collation.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count`
FROM visitor_page vp JOIN
     dealer_visitors dv
     ON vp.dealer_visitor_id = dv.id
WHERE vp.date_time BETWEEN '2021-02-01 05:51:00' AND '2021-03-21 05:50:00' AND
     dv.dealer_id = 15;
```

The best indexes are on `dealer_visitors(dealer_id, date_time, id)` and `visitor_page(dealer_visitor_id)`.

An index only on `date` helps a bit.  But you are retrieving a month's worth of data and that might be a lot of data to process.  Having `dealer_id` as the first column in the index will restrict the data to only the rows for that dealer in that time frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response. These indexes have been created, I have shared the schema design which shows that

Comment: @JawadChughtai - One index on three columns is not the same as three indexes on one column each.